# Async with python Flask

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have this function to render an `API` page:

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
async def index():
    response = {}
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.args.get('sku'):

        u = "https://....."
        r = async_store_check(u)
        response['status'] = 200
        response['data'] = await r
        return response



..... # other code
```

and this function to make the request:

```
def async_store_check(url):
   """
    performs asynchronous get requests
   """
  async def get_all(url):
      async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
          async def fetch(url):
              async with session.get(url) as response:
                  await parseResponse(response)
          return await asyncio.gather(url)
 return get_all(url)
```

and to parse the response:

```
def parseResponse(res):
  """
    parses response generated by the endpoint
  """ 
  if res.status_code == 200:
     # A successful response, parse the response
     response = res.json()
     return response
```

and then I run the app using waitress:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  print("Server is running on port 8000, Url: http://localhost:8000")
  print("Press Ctrl+C to quit")
  serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

But I get:

> TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required

Note, I'm fairly new to asyncio, and flask in general, So any advice with a solution is greatly appreciated.

**TRACEBACK**

```
ERROR:main:Exception on /api [GET] Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "/Users/s/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()   
File "/Users/s/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)   
File "/Users/s/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()   
File "/Users/s/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args) 
File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 223, in __call__
     return call_result.result()   
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 437, in result
     return self.__get_result()   
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 389, in __get_result
     raise self._exception   
File "/Library/Python/3.8/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 292, in main_wrap
     result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)   
File "/Users/s/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/s/s/main.py", line 22, in index
     **response['data'] = await r   
File "/Users/s/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/s/s/main.py", line 58, in get_all
     return await asyncio.gather(url)   
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 824, in gather
     fut = ensure_future(arg, loop=loop)   
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 684, in ensure_future
     raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is ' TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

Comment: `parseResponse` isn't awaitable I'd say

Comment: Note that when having an Exception, it's a good idea to share the full stracktrace, so we can see which line raised it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flas is sync library. You'd better to rewrite your async function using requests. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/
Example:

```
import requests
    
def store_check(url):
   response = requests.get(url)
   return response.text # return response.json()
```

Or you can use FastApi. It is async library for web development.
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/

Comment: FYI, Flask 2.x now supports async routes and functions: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/async-await/. And the requests library is not recommended for async prog as it is sync by design. It's better to use other libs like httpx (which is the same lib suggested by FastAPI for making test requests).